# Is there any way to stream the screens of the application real time IOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios9.2

I had an IOS application in which i need to stream my app screens with another application user in real time.I need to do this within the boundary of my application so that one can see what the other doing in the application in real time,Was anybody know how to achieve this?can anybody guide me to the right approach in achieving this?